# SQL: How to fill empty cells with next available value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I wanted to have the value of the null columns from the next available value.

[image]

I tried this code but I got the previous value

```
DROP TABLE #X
CREATE TABLE #X
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,v INT
);

INSERT INTO #X
SELECT 121 UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL 
UNION ALL SELECT 312 UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 123 UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL 
UNION ALL SELECT 415 UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 200;

SELECT * FROM #X;

DECLARE @v INT;

UPDATE #x WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET @v = v = CASE WHEN v IS NULL THEN @v ELSE v END
OPTION(MAXDOP 0);

SELECT * FROM #x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data has only one value per item code.  If that is true of your data in general, you can simply do:

```
select t.*, max(amount) over (partition by item_code)
from t;
```

If you want to update the amount then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(amount) over (partition by item_code) as new_amount
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set amount = new_amount
    where amount is null;
```

Comment: I have ITEM and PERIOD pk.